# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [taskPackageId]

Tags: java, hibernate

```
IF (((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM com.abc.domain.dcm.Program AS p
                    INNER JOIN p.programServiceLevelConfigs AS pslc
                    INNER JOIN pslc.taskPackages AS taskPackages
                    WHERE taskPackages.id = :taskPackageId) > 0) OR
            ((SELECT COUNT(*) from com.abc.domain.dcm.HcsEnrollmentBhpSetup hbs
                    INNER JOIN hbs.taskPackageMap
                    WHERE elements(hbs.taskPackageMap.id) = :taskPackageId) > 0))
        SELECT 1
    ELSE
        SELECT 0
```

I am setting the query parameter:

```
query.setParameter("taskPackageId", taskPackageId);
```

On executing the above HQL Query, I get the following the exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [taskPackageId]
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:379)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the whole code?

Comment: This is all the relevant code. My HQL is embedded in xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `if...else` statement in HQL. May be [CASE expression](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e2273) will help you.

Comment: You're correct. Even UNION is not yet supported within HQL https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1050. CASE expression wasn't useful given my requirements.